# Create a list of tuples excluding on tuple in the list

Tags: list, python-2.7, set

I have a list of tuples and I want to create another list that doesn't contain a specific tuple from that list.

Example:

```
mylist = [(a,b), (c,d), (e,f)]  
selected = (c,d)  
operation_between(list, selected)  
newlist = [(a,b), (e,f)]
```

The most simple way to do that is using a for loop, for iterating through mylist and inserting to newlist if `current_item != selected`.  Is there any better way?

I thought of converting the list to a set and then using the `-` operator to remove the selected tuple from the set. But using `set(mylist)` only created a set with one item, the list.
Then to fix that I think to use list comprehension, but this implies a for-loop again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just make a list comprehension filtering for what you don't want?

`mylist2 = [(x, y) for (x, y) in mylist if (x, y) != (c, d)]`

Comment: +1 for list comprehension if `newlist` must be a copy. btw, you don't need to unpack the tuple: `newlist = [item for item in mylist if item != selected]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `list.remove()` if you want to alter `mylist`:

```
mylist.remove(selected)
```

If you want a new copy of `mylist` without the element in question, use the `list()` constructor to make a new list instead, then call `remove()` on the new list:

```
newlist = list(mylist)
newlist.remove(selected)
```

Comment: +1 for `list.remove` if mylist must be modified inplace.